# Strange Right Margin in Mobile View

Tags: css, mobile, responsive-design

I'm having a strange issue and am hoping someone can see what I can't.

In a mobile view **only**, I am getting a right margin that is outside of the body. This only happens if I am using a device emulator or looking at it on an actual phone.

The red arrows point to the strange margin.

Have a look here: http://chizzledesigns.com/mobileissue.html

[image: Image of mobile emulator in chrome]

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `padding-left` for the signup form in `footer` is causing the page to show the scrollbar.

```
footer > div.social-media, footer > form#signup {
    padding-left: 10%;
}
```

Comment: A width of 100% and a padding-left of 10% would do it! 
Sharp eye, thank you!